# Angular material 5.2.4 - no table data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have problem with angular material table. I can't figure out why it doesn't work.Plugin works, pagination too, I can log to console data from http but plugin doesn't display rows.
Data for table is array of objects, and it looks same as in angular example

.html

```html
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="" matSort matSortActive="name" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nazwa</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.name }}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Opis</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.description }}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSize]="30">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

.ts

```ts
  @Component({
        selector: 'app-servicepointstablecomponent',
        templateUrl: './servicepointstable.component.html'
    })

@Injectable()
export class ServicepointstableComponent implements OnInit{

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
displayedColumns = ['name', 'description'];

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@Output() forDisplayRow = new EventEmitter<ServicePoint>();

resultsLength = 0;
isLoadingResults = true;
isRateLimitReached = false;

public selectedRow: ServicePoint;

constructor(private tableService: TableService) {
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 1);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
        .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
            this.isLoadingResults = true;
            return this.tableService!.getTableDataNew2<ServicePoint>(
                this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
        }),
        map(data => {

            this.isLoadingResults = false;
            this.isRateLimitReached = false;
            //this.resultsLength = data.total_count;
            this.resultsLength = 100;
            console.log(data);
            return data.items;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
            this.isLoadingResults = false;

            this.isRateLimitReached = true;
            return observableOf([]);
        })
        ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data);
}

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); 
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); 
}

onSelect(row: ServicePoint): void {
    this.tableService.getRowNew<ServicePoint>(row.idServicePoint).subscribe(rr => {
    this.selectedRow = rr; console.log(rr);
        this.forDisplayRow.emit(rr);});
}

onDelete(row: ServicePoint): void {
    console.log(`delete row ${row.description} ${row.name}`);
}
```

}

Comment: `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();` is wrong you need to define the generic for the table source

Comment: try  `this.dataSource.data = Object.values(data);`

Answer (score 0):

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
```

Missing something there buddy !

And there

```
.subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data)
```

That's not how you create a new data source.
Use the first syntax :

```
.subscribe(data => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data))
```

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work:/
I change to    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource <ServicePoint>();
and modified subscribe method.

Comment: That's not very explicit. What does it do exactly ? Please create an [mcve] so that we can fiddle with it

Comment: I would argue about `.subscribe(data => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data))` why would not `.subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data)` this work? and if that's the case what about [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vovrvojjnyk?file=app%2Ftable-http-example.ts)

Comment: Argue as much as you want, that's not my problem, that's yours. If you want to know why, look at the implementation of both. I'm giving you a working solution, feel free to not take it, I'm just following the documentation.

Comment: Thank you once again, the problem was data source, generic method should return array and I forget about brackets... silly thing and two hours lost...